# Angular 6 app: Can't resolve 'http' in \node_modules\ts-odatajs\lib\odata

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular5, angular6

I have just upgraded my angular 5 application to angular 6.

So far it works fine but i am getting some errors as soon as I import oData from the npm package 'ts-odatajs'. So simply by doing this in any component:

```
import { oData } from 'ts-odatajs';
oData.json
```

Then I get the error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/ts-odatajs/lib/odata/net.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
>   'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\angular6Test\v6test\node_modules\ts-odatajs\lib\odata'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/ts-odatajs/lib/odata/net.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'https' in
>   'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\angular6Test\v6test\node_modules\ts-odatajs\lib\odata'

Does anyone have any idea of why this might be happening? is it webpack or am I missing something else?

Thanks! :)

**EDIT**

A little update: I also have the exact same error as in this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10625

I have solved it by adding the following to my tsconfig.json file

```
  "jszip": [
    "../node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.js"
  ],
```

I have of course tried similar things for my posted issue but I still can't seem to get rid of the error.

Seems also to be related to this post but there is no real solutions there to find: https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/issues/191

Comment: Can you please check ts-odatajs dependency is httpmodule or httpClientModule?

Comment: In the source code file of the file net.js it says var http = require('http'); and var https = require('https'). In package.json i see no dependencies of either. And it is these 2 lines that the error is reffering to.

Comment: Seems like that package internally uses nodejs HTTP module. Can you check ts-odatajs supports AOT compilation and Typescript?

Comment: I guess it does because it worked fine when I was using angular5  :)

Comment: We tried accessing 'ts-odatajs' npm package. its returning some error. will check once it is available.